# C++ Cygwin CMake Error: " fatal: cannot change to ' ' No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, cmake

Using Cygwin in Windows I'm trying to build C++ project, that was sent to me, using cmake
after many trials to get it build successfully and at the last step I get this error

```
fatal: cannot change to '/cygdrive/d/project/C++/project1': No such file or directory
fatal: cannot change to '/cygdrive/d/project/C++/project1/lib/googletest':
```

Mainly this directory `d:\project\c++\project1` is the root directry that I executed the `cmake .` commaind in and the gtest library is aready there in the same folder.

My CMAKELists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
project(Project1-Solution)
find_package(Threads)
find_package(Git QUIET)

# Set compiler flags
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors -g")

# Make sure we have cloned googletest
if(GIT_FOUND AND EXISTS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/.git")
    execute_process(COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} -C ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} submodule update --init --recursive)
    execute_process(COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} -C ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/googletest checkout tags/release-1.8.1)
endif()
# Make sure GTest is built
include(gtest.cmake)

# Include project headers
include_directories(./include)
# Define the source files and dependencies for the executable
set(SOURCE_FILES
    src/Handler.cpp
    src/AllocationTracker.cpp
    tests/main.cpp
    tests/HandlerTest.cpp
    tests/moreTests.cpp
)
# Make the project root directory the working directory when we run
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
add_executable(testing ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_dependencies(testing gtest)
target_link_libraries(testing gtest ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

Comment: @Scheff . Yes /usr/bin/cmake

Comment: @Scheff yes typo. Modified it. the directory name is fine.